# Setting html in jquery with angularjs expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We are working on a legacy code that has a combination of angularJs, and javascript (jquery). We need i18n. Lots of the changes happening in general js files by setting the HTML on the fly. I am using pipe in the text so the angular take care of it. In some cases, it sets the value as it is instead of using the expression. 
`$("#exampleId").html("{{'exampleKey' | translate}}");`
I am sure combining these technology is not good idea but we cannot rewrite the code for now.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

@bahar erf. It would make more sense to create a $scope.exampleId variable and use that in the #exampleId element. In the controller set $scope.exampleId and it will automagically update in the view. That's the point of the angularjs framework, it handles those DOM changes so you don't have to use JQuery for those types of changes in the view.

```
<input ng-model="exampleId" />

or if displayed

<span>{{exampleId}}</span>`
```